# Undefined variable & issue with smof_data

Tags: php, variables

i'm helping my collegue with his current page and I've stucked with an error:

> Undefined variable: alignment

It reffers to the following piece of code:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'avada_page_title_bar' ) ) {
    /**
     * Render the HTML markup of the page title bar
     * @param  string $title                Main title; page/post title or custom title set by user
     * @param  string $subtitle             Subtitle as custom user setting
     * @param  string $secondary_content    HTML markup of the secondary content; breadcrumbs or search field
     *
     * @return void                         Content is directly echoed
     **/
    function avada_page_title_bar( $title, $subtitle, $secondary_content ) {
        global $smof_data;
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();

        // Check for the secondary content
        $content_type = 'none';
        if ( strpos( $secondary_content, 'searchform' ) !== FALSE ) {
            $content_type = 'search';
        } elseif ( $secondary_content != '' ) {
            $content_type = 'breadcrumbs';
        }

        // Check the position of page title
        if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, 'pyre_page_title_text_alignment' ) && 
             get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'pyre_page_title_text_alignment', TRUE ) != 'default' 
        ) {
            $alignment = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'pyre_page_title_text_alignment', TRUE );
        } elseif ( $smof_data['page_title_alignment'] ) {
            $alignment = $smof_data['page_title_alignment'];
        }

        // Render the page title bar
        echo sprintf( '<div class="fusion-page-title-bar fusion-page-title-bar-%s fusion-page-title-bar-%s">', $content_type, $alignment );
            echo '<div class="fusion-page-title-row">';
                echo '<div class="fusion-page-title-wrapper">';
                    echo '<div class="fusion-page-title-captions">';
                        if( $title ) {
                            // Add entry-title for rich snippets
                            $entry_title_class = '';
                            if ( ! $smof_data['disable_date_rich_snippet_pages'] ) { 
                                $entry_title_class = ' class="entry-title"';
                            }                   
                            echo sprintf( '<h1%s>%s</h1>', $entry_title_class, $title );

                            if ( $subtitle ) {
                                echo sprintf( '<h3>%s</h3>', $subtitle );
                            }

                            if ( get_field( "data_i_miejsce_koncertu" ) && is_single() ) {
                                echo ( '<h3>' . get_field( "data_i_miejsce_koncertu" ) . '</h3>' );
                            }
                        }

                        // Render secondary content on center layout
                        if ( $alignment == 'center') {
                            if ( fusion_get_option( 'page_title_bar_bs', 'page_title_breadcrumbs_search_bar', $post_id ) != 'none' ) {
                                echo '<div class="fusion-page-title-secondary">';
                                    echo $secondary_content;
                                echo '</div>';
                            }
                        }

                    echo '</div>';

                    // Render secondary content on left/right layout
                    if ( $alignment != 'center' ) {
                        if ( fusion_get_option( 'page_title_bar_bs', 'page_title_breadcrumbs_search_bar', $post_id ) != 'none' ) {
                            echo '<div class="fusion-page-title-secondary">';
                                echo $secondary_content;
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    }

                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Error is linked with following lines:

```
echo sprintf( '<div class="fusion-page-title-bar fusion-page-title-bar-%s fusion-page-title-bar-%s">', $content_type, $alignment );
```

AND

```
if ( $alignment == 'center') {
```

AND

```
            if ( $alignment != 'center' ) {
```

Why is that? $alignment is defined at the beginning..

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$alignment` is only being set conditionally by the following lines:

```
if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, 'pyre_page_title_text_alignment' ) && 
             get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'pyre_page_title_text_alignment', TRUE ) != 'default' 
) {
    $alignment = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'pyre_page_title_text_alignment', TRUE );
} elseif ( $smof_data['page_title_alignment'] ) {
    $alignment = $smof_data['page_title_alignment'];
}
```

If neither the `if()` nor the `elseif()` conditions are met, the variable is never set. Probably there is an initialisation with a default value missing:

```
$alignment = 'center';
```

This should be placed above the aforementioned lies of code.

Comment: hm.. I've checked the core file (full functions.php of the template) and there was no global variable set ;/ and with that it works. When I've copied this specific function to my template - not.

Comment: Maybe it is defined elsewhere, not in functions.php. Via `global $alignment;` the defnition could also be buried in some function or even inside a class method.